# Does HTTP compression force chunked encoding?

Tags: http, http-headers

As I see in *Transfer-length issues* section [1](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html), if *transfer-length* and *entity-length* differs the sender is not allowed to use the *Content-Length* header at all.

So if message has *Content-Encoding* header with value different than *identity* it cannot use *Content-Length*.

Does it mean *chunked encoding* should be ultimately specified for, say, gzipped content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are (a) looking at very old documents (see RFC 7230 instead), and (b) confuse *transfer* codings with *content* codings. Use of *content* coding gzip doesn't require chunked *transfer* coding; it's just used a lot when the gzip compression happens on the fly and you don't know the content length beforehand.